Excel form VBA enters date as US format when i need it as AU
I have created a VBA form to enter data into a table. one of the data fields is a date, but it keeps entering the data as mm/dd/yyyy, but I need it to be entered as dd/mm/yyyy. If I change the column to "text" it shows how I want it, but when I use "sort" the date is sorts by number descending not date descending. Is there a way to change the date to dd/mm/yyyy?
---- My current code is; ----
`Private Sub cmdAdd_Click()

Dim iRow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("ClientData")

'find first empty row in database
iRow = ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row + 1


'copy the data to the database
'use protect and unprotect lines,
'     with your password
'     if worksheet is protected
With ws
Worksheets("ClientData").Unprotect Password:="Password"
'  .Unprotect Password:="Password"
  .Cells(iRow, 1).Value = Me.txtDate.Value
  .Cells(iRow, 2).Value = Me.txtStarttime.Value
  .Cells(iRow, 3).Value = Me.txtEndtime.Value
  .Cells(iRow, 4).Value = Me.txtTotal.Value
  .Cells(iRow, 5).Value = Me.txtProgress.Value
  .Cells(iRow, 6).Value = Me.txtStaff.Value
'  .Protect Password:="Password"
Worksheets("ClientData").Protect Password:="Password"
End With

'clear the data
Me.txtDate.Value = ""
Me.txtStarttime.Value = ""
Me.txtEndtime.Value = ""
Me.txtTotal.Value = ""
Me.txtProgress.Value = ""
Me.txtStaff.Value = ""`

End Sub


Use the cell's NumberFormat to set the date format you want. If you open the Format dialog in Excel, you can see samples of the formats supported by looking at the Custom tab.

Try converting your textbox value in to a date data type:  .Cells(iRow, 1).Value = CDATE(Me.txtDate.Value)

Convert Date String to Date

I have assumed that the dates are entered in the text box using the d/m/yyyy (DMY) format and that you want to write this date to the cell.
Then you could replace Me.txtDate.Value with GetDateValue(Me.txtDate.Value) using the following function:

Function GetDateValue( _
    ByVal DateString As String, _
    Optional ByVal DateFormatYMD As String = "DMY", _
    Optional ByVal DateDelimiter As String = "/", _
    Optional ByVal ShowFailMessage As Boolean = False) _
As Date
    Const PROC_TITLE As String = "Get Date Value"
    On Error GoTo ClearError
    
    Dim ArrDate() As String: ArrDate = Split(DateString, DateDelimiter)
    
    Dim yPos As Long: yPos = InStr(1, DateFormatYMD, "Y", vbTextCompare) - 1
    Dim mPos As Long: mPos = InStr(1, DateFormatYMD, "M", vbTextCompare) - 1
    Dim dPos As Long: dPos = InStr(1, DateFormatYMD, "D", vbTextCompare) - 1

    GetDateValue = DateSerial(ArrDate(yPos), ArrDate(mPos), ArrDate(dPos))

ProcExit:
    Exit Function
ClearError:
    If ShowFailMessage Then
        MsgBox "Could not retrieve the date from """ & DateString & """ in """ _
            & DateFormatYMD & """ format delimited by """ & DateDelimiter _
            & """!" & vbLf & vbLf _
            & "Run-time error [" & Err.Number & "]:" & vbLf & vbLf _
            & Err.Description, vbCritical, PROC_TITLE
    End If
    Resume ProcExit
End Function


Additionally, format the cell as required with e.g.:
.Cells(iRow, 1).NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"




The following illustrates how the function works.
Main
Sub Test()

    Dim MyDate As Date, DateString As String
    
    DateString = "5/8/2024" ' i.e. 5th August (Correct)
    MyDate = GetDateValue(DateString, "DMY", "/", True)
    PrintResultAndReset MyDate, DateString
        
    DateString = "5/8/2024" ' i.e. 5th August (Wrong Date Format ('MDY'))
    MyDate = GetDateValue(DateString, "MDY", "/", True)
    PrintResultAndReset MyDate, DateString
        
    DateString = "5-8-2024" ' i.e. 5th August (Wrong Delimiter ('/'))
    MyDate = GetDateValue(DateString, "DMY", "/", True)
    PrintResultAndReset MyDate, DateString
    
    DateString = "5-8-2024" ' i.e. 5th August (Correct)
    MyDate = GetDateValue(DateString, "DMY", "-", True)
    PrintResultAndReset MyDate, DateString
        
    DateString = "582024" ' i.e. 5th August (Wrong Date String)
    MyDate = GetDateValue(DateString, "DMY", "-", True)
    PrintResultAndReset MyDate, DateString
        
End Sub

Help
Sub PrintResultAndReset( _
        ByRef MyDate As Date, _
        ByVal DateString As String)
    If MyDate = 0 Then
        Debug.Print DateString, "Something went wrong!"
    Else
        Debug.Print DateString, Format(MyDate, "mm\/dd\/yyyy")
        MyDate = 0
    End If
    
End Sub

Result in the Immediate Window Ctrl+G
5/8/2024      08/05/2024
5/8/2024      05/08/2024
5-8-2024      Something went wrong!
5-8-2024      08/05/2024
582024        Something went wrong!

Message Boxes



This is derived from handling a string as Date in Excel.
Excel try to recognize a Date first in the US format and if not succeeded then the local is used.
What you can do that convert in the code the string of the date to a US date format string and assign this to the cell.
Something like this
datetext = "2/7/2024"   'Me.txtDate.Value
sl1 = InStr(datetext, "/")
sl2 = InStr(sl1 + 1, datetext, "/")
.Cells(irow, 1).Value = Mid(datetext, sl1 + 1, sl2 - sl1 - 1) & "/" & Left(datetext, sl1 - 1) & "/" & Mid(datetext, sl2 + 1)

In this example datetext is the inputted date to convert.
If there are no second "/" in the string an error is generated.
